# Does Windows Phone 7 cache web request?

Tags: caching, windows-phone-7

In Windows Phone 7 Do calls to `WebClient` and `HttpWebRequest` use a caching system or do they ALWAYS pull from the web?

Also if I use `<Image Source="http://www.images.com/someimage.jpg"/>` does the image cache or does it pull from the web ever time the app loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HI Jamey,

WebClient and HttpWebRequest urls are cached which causes problems when fetching the same URL but wanting fresh results. One workaround is to make something unique in the query string.

Images aren't cached prompting people to develop solutions to this.

[One-time Cached Images in Windows Phone 7 « Ben.geek.nz](http://www.ben.geek.nz/2010/07/one-time-cached-images-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: Yes but note that caching of requests by WebClient and HttpWebRequest can be influenced by use of appropriate HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, then you can set the cache-control header.

I've had great luck with using 'cache-control: no-cache'

There is also a way in iis7.5 to set the cache-control for static files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cache images in your app I have got a solution for you. It is [JetImageLoader](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), I created it for application, where we need to load, cache and show big amount of logos, icons and so on.

It can be used as binding converter, so *you should not even change your code! Just update your XAMLs!*

Please, check out [samples in repository](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader), you'll love it ;)

**Features:**

- Caching on disk
- Caching in memory
- Fully asynchronous
- Available as binding converter or programmatically from your code
- Fully open source, fork and improve it!

Here is the example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Converter={StaticResource MyAppJetImageLoaderConverter}}"/>
```

P.S. I am sorry, that I copying my answer from another questions, but image caching on windows phone is huge problem and I want to share my solution, so everybody can use it and improve for developers community